# Android ListView: how to get the items on screen?

Tags: android, listview

I want to get the items which are on the screen.
For example:
   item No.4 and part of item No.5 can be seen. How to get the Views of the two?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`getFirstVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition()) to get the index of the first visible item on screen, and [`getLastVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition()) to get the index of the last item on screen.